# Last sunday of previous week in SSIS

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, etl, msbi

I want a SSIS expression which will give me the sunday date of last week.

Corresponding sql server query looks like :

select convert(date,DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, convert(date,@report_dt)), -1))

I want the same result in SSIS expression.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your date is held in a variable called `report_dt`, this works for me:

```
(DT_DATE)LEFT((DT_WSTR, 30)DATEADD("Day", -1 * (DATEPART("Weekday", @[User::report_dt]) + 7), @[User::report_dt]), 10)
```

However not sure if this is region safe - but it works in the UK.

Comment: Hi,
I was able to see RIGHT function in the String functions folder in SSIS, but it was not able to recognize LEFT function. Am I missing something?

Comment: I am using the latest version version so maybe it's a new feature, how about using SUBSTRING instead?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the Sunday of last week using the variable `report_dt`:

```
(DT_DBDATE)DATEPART("dw",@[User::report_dt]) == (DT_DBDATE)1 ? @[User::report_dt] : DATEADD("day",-(DATEPART("dw",@[User::report_dt]) - 1),@[User::report_dt])
```

It's casted as `DT_DBTIME` so only the date is returned.